# How can I check if a boolean variable is still true for some amount of times?

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how I can check if the initialized boolean variable has still the same value (true/false) for some amount of time

I was thinking of using NSTimer, but I believe there is a better way to solve this way.

Is there any good way to check if the boolean variable has still the same value for some amount of time?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you describe your problem a little more. As it stands it’s hard to provide any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a simple wrapper:

```swift
struct WrappedBoolean {
    private(set) var value: Bool
    private(set) var wasChanged = false

    init(with value: Bool) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func set(value: Bool) {
        self.value = value
        wasChanged = true
    }

}
```

We can also use [generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) to use the wrapper for all data types:

```swift
struct WrappedValue<T> {
    private(set) var value: T
    private(set) var wasChanged = false

    init(with value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func set(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        wasChanged = true
    }

}
```